# Why is my code returning the last value of an array instead of returning a result for each item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> You will be given an array of objects (associative arrays in PHP)
>   representing data about developers who have signed up to attend the
>   next coding meetup that you are organising.
>
> Your task is to return an array where each object will have a new
>   property 'greeting' with the following string value:
>
> > Hi < firstName here >, what do you like the most about < language here >?
>
> For example, given the following input array:
>
> ```
> var list1 = [
>
> { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' },
>
>   { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python' }
> ]
> ```
>
> your function should return the following array:
>
> ```
> [
>   { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java',
>     greeting: 'Hi Sofia, what do you like the most about Java?'
>   },
>
>   { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python',
>     greeting: 'Hi Lukas, what do you like the most about Python?'
>   }];
> ```

So far I have this:

```
var count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

  count +=1;

    list.forEach (function greet(string){

    string.Greeting = "Hi " + list[i].firstName + ",what do you like most about " + list[i].language + "?";

    });  // For each object in array, add string "greeting:" using function

  }

console.log(list);

}
```

This returns the greeting, but returns the last person in the array's name and language, rather than each individual separately.

Comment: You're iterating twice: once with your `for (var i = 0;...` iteration, and once with your `list.forEach` iteration. You should choose one, you do not need to use both methods of iteration, and iterating inside an iteration is the cause of your issue

Comment: Consider using the array map function?

Comment: Also, in the function inside your `forEach`, you refer to the argument as `string` -- the argument is the developer object itself. `list.forEach(function(developer) {...` would be a more appropriate name for the variable

Comment: I recommend that one of the first things you do in learning Javascript is learn how to use breakpoints in Chrome Devtools - snippets. You can test your code and see exactly what's happening. For example, if you set a breakpoint in your `forEach` callback function, you could see what arguments your callback is getting, which would help you understand what a `forEach` function does

Comment: @TKoL you have been incredibly helpful, thank you for taking your time out to explain such things!

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm not sure what they are yet, consider it written on todays to do list, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `for of` loop.

Here is the working example.

```js
const list1 = [

{ firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' },

  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python' }
];



for (let person of list1){
  person.greeting = `Hi ${person.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${person.language}?`
}

console.log(list1);
```

Comment: @CocoFlade can you please accept this as an answer if this worked for you.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me as i've only been on this for 24hrs, the green tick to the left of your work is that correct?

Comment: @CocoFlade yes thats correct, but the thing is all of them are correct, its all about approach which you think is right.

Answer (score 1):

As @TKoL says, you are wrongly mixing for and forEach. You just need to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  list[i].greeting = `Hi ${list[i].firstName}, what do you like most about ${list[i].language}?`;
}
```

or

```
list.forEach(l => l.greeting = `Hi ${l.firstName}, what do you like most about ${l.language}?`);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, there was no chance I'd have spotted that issue alone!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You should use a `.map()` operator instead of a `forEach` as it can return a new array, like this:

```
const newList = list.map (function greet(person){
    return {greeting : "Hi " + person.firstName + ",what do you like most about " + person.language + "?", ...person};
});  
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: This seems to be a common theme in the comments, something I hadnt heard of. Thank you for letting me know it really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code:

```
var count = 0;
var list = [
    {
        firstName: 'Sofia',
        lastName: 'I.',
        country: 'Argentina',
        continent: 'Americas',
        age: 35,
        language: 'Java'
    },

    {
        firstName: 'Lukas',
        lastName: 'X.',
        country: 'Croatia',
        continent: 'Europe',
        age: 35,
        language: 'Python'
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    count += 1;

    list[i].Greeting =
        'Hi ' +
        list[i].firstName +
        ',what do you like most about ' +
        list[i].language +
        '?';
}

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, I can see where i'm going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to add a property to an object:

```
function addGreeting(person) {
  return {...person, greeting: `Hi ${person.name}, what do you like most about ${person.language}?`};
}
```

And map your array elements to modified ones:

```
people = people.map(person => addGreeting(person));
```

Comment: This is not a correct way to use map. Why do you need to create a whole new array just to add a property to each element? GB will do its job eventually, but there's no need to do this at all.

Comment: This absolutely is the correct way to use map. And there is nothing to garbage collect, return value of map is assigned to already existing reference, there is no garbage.

Comment: You had an array inside a variable ```people```. Then you create a new array and store it in the variable ```people```. What happens with the first array? Yes, the first array will be managed by the GC.

Comment: Either way, thank you to both of you, you've been a great help and given me plenty to look at!